# Grafana Postgres Error When Using Where Query That Can Have Multiple Values

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2, grafana

I have a Grafana website pulling from a PostgreSQL database. In the dashboard, I am trying to create a line graph, with a filter set on two of the columns (project and epic). The filter works fine for the project (probably because there is just one project value, and all rows in the database are set with that value).

But when I try to filter on the "epic", it will only work for a single choice. The 'All' choice gives me the below error:
`pq: syntax error at or near ","`

Below is a screenshot of how I'm trying to configure this filter.
[image]

Also note the epic is tied to a variable, and below is a screenshot of how I've setup that variable
[image]

Edit

Requested Generated SQL

```sql
{
  "request": {
    "url": "api/tsdb/query",
    "method": "POST",
    "data": {
      "from": "1577958613797",
      "to": "1609224964157",
      "queries": [
        {
          "refId": "A",
          "intervalMs": 21600000,
          "maxDataPoints": 1470,
          "datasourceId": 4,
          "rawSql": "SELECT\n  \"timestamp\" AS \"time\",\n  cycle_time AS \"cycle_time\"\nFROM issue_metrics\nWHERE\n  $__timeFilter(\"timestamp\") AND\n  project = 'LUSFPRO3' AND\n  epic = 'LUSFPRO3-68','LUSFPRO3-2','LUSFPRO3-69'\nORDER BY 1",
          "format": "time_series"
        }
      ]
    },
    "hideFromInspector": false
  },
  "response": {
    "results": {
      "A": {
        "error": "pq: syntax error at or near \",\"",
        "refId": "A",
        "meta": {
          "executedQueryString": "SELECT\n  \"timestamp\" AS \"time\",\n  cycle_time AS \"cycle_time\"\nFROM issue_metrics\nWHERE\n  \"timestamp\" BETWEEN '2020-01-02T09:50:13.797Z' AND '2020-12-29T06:56:04.157Z' AND\n  project = 'LUSFPRO3' AND\n  epic = 'LUSFPRO3-68','LUSFPRO3-2','LUSFPRO3-69'\nORDER BY 1"
        },
        "series": null,
        "tables": null,
        "dataframes": null
      }
    },
    "message": "pq: syntax error at or near \",\""
  }
}
```

Comment: Please show `Generated SQL`

Comment: @JanGaraj Just posted an update with the generatte SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That multivalue variable generates wrong SQL syntax:

```
epic = 'LUSFPRO3-68','LUSFPRO3-2','LUSFPRO3-69'
```

GUI editor is good only for simple queries. Toogle to text edit mode and update `epic` condition in the query to:

```
epic IN ($Epic)
```

so that generates correct SQL syntax:

```
epic IN ('LUSFPRO3-68','LUSFPRO3-2','LUSFPRO3-69')
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! Is there anyway to get the query builder to use the 'IN' syntax vs the '=' or am I forced to using custom SQL commands from now on if I want to add onto this?

Comment: Click on the `=` in the GUI editor and it should offer all available options. Actually, `IN` is also there.